# Mercado Pago: MVC, error al configurar URL de recepcion de pagos

Tags: mvc, mercadopago

estoy haciendo un modulo de pago con la api de mercadopago, y a la hora de configurar la url para la recepcion de notificaciones de pago en la página de mercadopago, me da el error **"La URL ingresada no responde un HTTP status correcto. Debe responder 200 o 201"**.

Mi aplicación esta hecha en MVC, y la acción que quiero configurar es:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpStatusCodeResult MisNotificaciones(string topic, string id)
{
     return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
}
```

Alguna idea de como debo hacer el metodo o como debo poner la URL en **https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/ipn-notifications**?

Ahora mismo trato de configurar **http://example.com/mercadopago/misnotificaciones**

Comment: que version de mvc estas usando?

Comment: Estoy usando MVC4, con el VS2013

Comment: y cuando ves el response devuelve un codigo 200 mas alla del mensaje de mercado pago?

Comment: Si, devolvía 200. Lo probé con un rest y funcionaba bien.

Comment: si aun sigue este problema, antes del return prueba lo siguiente Response.StatusCode = 200;

Comment: quisiera saber como hiciste para implementar la API y en que ambito? ya que yo estoy haciendo una app que selecciona productos y eso se suma para que luego la persona lo pague mediante mercadopago. Tienes alguna guia o me sabrias explicar bien ya que la pagina no entiendo mucho. saludos,

Comment: sabes que yo implemente el consumo del API de mercado libre para las notificaciones, está trabajando perfecto, es decir, me envía notificaciones cada 2 segundos (+/-) por cada pregunta hasta que es respondida, sin embargo no entiendo muy bien la documentación de ML dice esto: "Enviaremos un POST a la callback URL y tu aplicación deberá confirmar mediante un HTTP 200 la recepción correcta. Caso contrario, el mensaje será considerado como “no recibido” y habrá una nueva tentativa de envío." Lo que no entiendo es como hacer para "confirmar" que he recibido la notificación bien y evitar que me sig

Answer (score 0):

Probé varias formas de devolver un **HttpStatusCodeResult** sin éxito.

En medio de la bronca, cree una vista común, que me devuelva una página HTML en blanco y antes del **return View()** puse mi código que quiero que se ejecuto al recibir la notificación de Mercado pago, y de esta manera si que funcionó.

Al ir a la página de MercadoPago y configurar mi URL puse **http://example.com/myController/myAction** y me lo tomo como correcto.

El código en mi controller es:

```
public ActionResult MisNotificaciones(string topic, int id)
{
    // LOGIC HERE

    return View();
}
```

y la vista correspondiente:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title></tile>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```